# Referencing css files in blazor

Tags: blazor

I noticed that non of the links to static css files are being used in blazor app.

Does it mean that all of the static css files are automatically imorted and can be referenced in code without a need to explicitly import them via script tag?

Comment: Are you sure? In the default templates the site.css file is referenced in the index.html (Blazor WebAssmebly) or _Hosts.cshtml (Blazor Server)

Comment: you are right, it didnt make any sense to check wwwroot/index.html. Does it mean that entire app uses index.html? What if I want to have multiple base index file for static content?

Comment: All pages use the index.html, hence the term Single Page Application. If this is new to you I would suggest you have a read up on what SPAs are and how they work. It will makes things a lot easier to reason about. I just published a blog post about routing in Blazor which kind of covers this (https://chrissainty.com/introduction-to-routing-in-blazor/). Might be worth a read.